# Type or Namespace does not exist Issue

Tags: c#, msbuild

I've tried to troubleshoot this issue from a large number of posts I've come across on the internet, but to no avail. I'm getting compile error my TFS Build Server. It compiles fine on my machine, but I'm getting errors like the following:

> ```
> Infrastructure\Data\DataContext.cs (6, 26)  
>
> The type or namespace name 'ModelConfiguration' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Infrastructure\Data\DataContext.cs (13, 32)  
>
> The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> ```

This is what my code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using TEST.Core.Models;
using TEST.Core.ResultSets;

namespace TEST.Infrastructure.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        #region Local Properties

        public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
```

I had just upgraded my projects from .NET 4 to .NET 4.6.1. I just upgraded Entity Framework to 6.2. It compile fine on my machine but when I checked everything in and I compiled on my TFS Build Server, it fails with those messages. I checked and all the packages were checked in as well.

Comment: When you "upgraded Entity Framework to 6.2" on your machine, did you check in the upgraded NuGet stuff to source control?  Does your build (on the build server) include a "Get packages from NuGet" step?  Have you looked a the build logs to see what version of EF you are referencing on the Build box?

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes. I made sure that all my packages were checked in. I checked to see if the reference was pointing to the DLL in the GAC but it's not. It's pointing to the .NET 4.6.1 folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the error message was showing an issue with `System.Data`, the real issue was that the `EntityFramework.dll` where it was being referenced wasn't checked in.

Comment: Just FYI, in C# / .NET the name of an assembly (e.g., `EntityFramework.dll`) isn't necessarily the same as the name of a namespace. An assembly can declare multiple namespaces, and a namespace can be declared in multiple assemblies. In your case, the missing type was [`DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx); that page lists both the namespace and the assembly, which in this case are different.